# Model built in Gödel's completeness theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Disclaimer : the question is very vague.

Today as I was thinking about the construction of a model for a set of formulas in Gödel's completeness theorem and I sort of felt that the construction is 'canonical' in some sense. I was thinking that is there any result connecting Gödel's model (call it G) to any other model of a set of formulas. Maybe something like Gödel's model can be embedded into/mapped to any other model such that the image satisfies the set formulas on their own.

My intuition is if we consider only canonical models, i.e. models where there is a corresponding closed term for each element in the model, then for any canonical model C there is a map f : G -> C. I think this is true for the Herbrand model for zeroth order logic.

Comment: "the question is very vague" - I agree.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the vote to close - I think this is a question which is by its nature difficult to articulate, and is clear enough to admit a good answer. I've upvoted and voted to reopen.

Comment: To the OP, note that we need to fix an ordering on the formulas in our language to start with. So that's a non-canonical feature right there.

Comment: In spite of the arbitrariness of the order you start with, there's surely something canonical about the models Henkin constructs, and so I'm curious to hear what a model theorist might have to say about in what sense such models are special. Seems like a good question to me, even if it turns out that there's nothing special about such models after all.

Answer (score 5):

Henkin models *(Godel's original proof was quite different)* do indeed satisfy a kind of "minimality" condition, but there are subtleties.

*A good further source is the (sadly hard to find) book [Henkin-Keisler models](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b102616).*

---

For any theory $T$, the set of closed terms in the language of $T$ modulo $T$-provable equality yields a structure in the language of $T$ in a natural way which I'll call "$Term(T)$" *(ignoring for the moment the issue that there may be no closed terms at all; if this bothers you, either work in the version of FOL which allows empty structures or assume our language contains at least one constant symbol)*. In general, $Term(T)$ need not satisfy $T$; however, if $T$ is complete and has the strong witness property, we will have $Term(T)\models T$. In this situation we do indeed have a very nice "minimality" property:

> Suppose $T$ is complete and has the witness property, and $M\models T$. Then there is a unique elementary embedding of $Term(T)$ into $M$, and the image of this embedding is exactly the set of definable elements of $M$.

Note that this is *stronger* than merely saying that $Term(T)$ is the **prime model** of $T$.

---

This says that "Henkin models" do enjoy a kind of minimality. However, there are subtleties here:

- The above ignores the part of the proof where we pass from our initial consistent theory $T_0$ to a theory $T\supseteq T_0$ (in a possibly larger language) which is complete, consistent, and has the strong witness property. There are many ways to do this, essentially depending on *how we order the formulas in our language*, and these different approaches generally yield different theories (and hence different models at the end of the day).
- Moreover, even fixing a single appropriate $T\supseteq T_0$, we still have the issue that the model of $T_0$ we produce at the end of the day isn't $Term(T)$ but rather the *reduct* of $Term(T)$ to the original language of $T_0$, and this restriction of language will in general kill the minimality observation above.

---

Let me end by mentioning a follow-up to the first bulletpoint above which I haven't seen treated before. Roughly speaking, given our starting theory $T_0$ we get an equivalence relation on orderings of formulas given by "yield the same model" *(there are actually a couple inequivalent approaches here, but ignore that for now)*. Intuitively, there is a connection between how coarse this relation is and how close to being complete and having the witness property $T$ is *(in particular, if we start with a theory which already is  complete and has the witness property, then the way we order formulas shouldn't impact anything since there's nothing we need to change)*. We have various tools for treating that sort of thing (e.g. descriptive set theory), so in principle there could be some interesting dividing lines to be drawn here. However, I haven't seen anything along these lines, and so I don't know if there's actually anything here.

Comment: What is the witness property?

Comment: @ArkaGhosh One way to phrase it is the following: for every formula of the form $\exists x_1,...,x_n\theta(x_1,...,x_n)$, there are constant symbols $c_1,...,c_n$ such that the theory prove $\theta(c_1,...,c_n)$. We could replace "constant symbol" with "closed term," or alternatively talk about explicit Skolem functions for all appropriate formulas, and get the same ultimate picture.

Comment: Aha! That is the exact condition I thought when I was trying to prove that there is a mapping from the Henkin model. But I thought that it was too strict.

Comment: @ArkaGhosh Nope, it's true (as long as the theory we use is "good enough" of course)!

Comment: By too strict I meant that it kind of guarantees the mapping.